# My c# database code isn't working not adding anything to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I recently made a help thread in here, and was told to watch youtube videos so I did. But the code I got didn't work, so I wanted to see if anyone here could see if maybe I had just misplaced something.

My table is called `Table`:

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table values('" +b.Navn+ "','"+b.Gmail+"', '"+b.GmailKode+"', '"+b.Alder+"')";

// cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); When I use this code, I get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'. Unexpected code."

con.Close();
```

Comment: Well. What kind of error are you facing? What do you expect from this code? You need to add more information so we can help you.

Comment: Of course, my bad. Whops. 
So, it's supposed to add the string b.Navn, then string b.Gmail, string b.GmailKode, and int b.Alder to the database, but right now it's just isn't adding anything.

Comment: Naming a table `table`, which is a reserved word in SQL, is a bad idea.  If it's SQL Server, you might try putting brackets around it `insert into [table]...`.

Comment: You created a table called literally `Table`?

Comment: Naming a table 'Table' is very bad idea, please use something else like 'table1'

Comment: Changed it to [table] as @PaulAbbott said and it works now! Thanks!

Comment: SQL Injection right there

Answer (score 0):

instead of keyword 'Table' in your query u should enter the actual 'tablename'

Comment: No my tablename is actually table. I'm just experimenting with the tables, so didn't think it needed a important name.

Comment: because Table is valid sql keyword, in case your table_name is actually 'Table' , u need to put it in brackets like: [Table]

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the column names.

Syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

**UPDATE**:

You can omit the definitions, if you specify the values for all columns, and in the order they were added to the table.

But the issue might be you call your table "table". If you use SQL Server, you can put the word "TABLE" in brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE] 
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

This way it won't be recognised as a keyword. But ultimately you should not name your tables "TABLE" or any other keyword.

Comment: Excluding the column names is valid SQL provided all columns are represented and in table order in the VALUES clause.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Are you sure? How sql will figure out field order if all my fields are same type? Just curious

Comment: You're right. I guess I never used that syntax because of the all and in order conditions. :)

Answer (score 0):

put the word Table in brackets [Table]
and make sure you are using all columns in order 
and to be safe you can use

```
"insert into [Table] (write you column name ,...) values('" +b.Navn+ "','"+b.Gmail+"', '"+b.GmailKode+"', '"+b.Alder+"')";

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Table] values('" +b.Navn+ "','"+b.Gmail+"', '"+b.GmailKode+"', '"+b.Alder+"')";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

con.Close();
```